# How to pass Github secrets to JSON file

Tags: json, github, github-actions

I wanted to pass secrets from a GitHub action to a JSON file in the same workflow.

```
# Github secrets
SECRET_TOKEN: 4321
```

In file.json the SECRET_TOKEN value needs to be fetched.

```
 # file.json
    {
       secret_token: "SECRET_TOKEN", # should fetch the SECRET_TOKEN from git action
       apiId: "blabla"
    }
```

> Expected Output:

```
# file.json
        {
           secret_token: "4321",
           apiId: "blabla"
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to use the [replace-tokens](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/replace-tokens) action, as example, suppose this json file:

<kbd>file.json</kbd>

```
{
   secret_token: "#{SECRET_TOKEN}#",
   apiId: "blabla"
}
```

the action:

```
- uses: cschleiden/replace-tokens@v1
  with:
    files: 'file.json'
  env:
    SECRET_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.SECRET_TOKEN }}
```

If you want to use a different token format, you can specify a custom token prefix/suffix. For example, to replace just tokens like `{SECRET_TOKEN} you could add:

```
- uses: cschleiden/replace-tokens@v1
  with:
    files: 'file.json'
    tokenPrefix: '{'
    tokenSuffix: '}'
  env:
    SECRET_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.SECRET_TOKEN }}
```

Comment: will SECRET_TOKEN in action can hold the value and pass to Json, I Had updated my expected output please have a look.

Comment: @Ansh of course: just follow the convention of the action about the prefix/suffix requirements. Sorry for the confusion of using the same name for all the variables

Answer (score 1):

You have several options - you can use pure bash and `jq` to achieve that or if you are not that experienced, an easier way will be to use one of existing actions from marketplace, like this one:

https://github.com/marketplace/actions/create-json

```
- name: create-json
  uses: jsdaniell/create-json@1.1.2
  with:
     name: "file.json"
     json: '{"app":"blabla", "secret_token":"${{ secrets.SECRET_TOKEN }}"}'
```